# Is there any experiment going on to test the TWO HIGGS DOUBLET MODEL?

Tags: particle-physics, field-theory, gauge

We know that the two higgs doublet model which is a beyond standard model theory predicts five higgs bosons.Is there any experiment that is going on to test this theory and if so have they found any evidence?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, CMS and ATLAS are the LHC experiments that are looking for predictions beyond the standard model, and setting limits. [For example:](https://cds.cern.ch/record/2320899/files/arXiv:1805.12191.pdf)

> A search for Higgs bosons that decay into a bottom quark-antiquark pair and are accompanied by at least one additional bottom quark is performed with the CMS detector. The data analyzed were recorded in proton-proton collisions at a centre-of-mass energy of $√s=13$ TeV at the LHC, corresponding to an integrated luminosity of $35.7 fb^−1$. The final state considered in this analysis is particularly sensitive to signatures of a Higgs sector beyond the standard model, as predicted in the generic class of two Higgs doublet models (2HDMs). No signal above the standard model back-ground expectation is observed. Stringent upper limits on the cross section times branching fraction are set for Higgs bosons with masses up to 1300 GeV. The results are interpreted within several MSSM and 2HDM scenarios.